# NetBeans form designer: Change layout after call to initComponents

Tags: java, netbeans, layout, designer, jpanel

I have a class that extends `javax.swing.JPanel`, it contains a single JButton. I've created the class in **NetBeans designer**. As such, I have a `initComponents()` function thats called from the class constructor.

What I want to do is when/if a function is called, I want to add a second button, and change the layout of the two buttons. Doing simply:

```
public void addSecond() {
    javax.swing.JButton secondButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    add(secondButton , java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Doesnt work, the new button doesnt show up. I tried a call to `invalidate()` as well but no luck.

- **How do I trigger a re-evaluation of the layout?**
- If said function is called more than once, what parts of the layout/buttons do I need to call dispose() on? Any other cleanup I should worry about?
- Would this be easier to handle if I don't use the NetBeans designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the layout of the panel before you add the button with `BorderLayout.CENTER`.  Also, you must remove and add the first button again and invoke the `revalidate()` method on the panel.

Change your addSecond() method as below and it should work.

```
private void addSecond() {
    JButton secondButton = new JButton("Button - 2");

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    remove(firstButton);
    add(firstButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(secondButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I had to completely recreate the layout instance, I'll change the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

when you changed the components in a way that changes the layout, you need to trigger the layout manager again by calling `revalidate()`. You can call it as often as you want.
For simple layouts just calling `repaint()` may be sufficient.

And actually unless you're doing dynamically changing panels (i.e. adding/removing components on the fly) you should use the netbeans designer, so all the Swing elements are in one place.

-- EDIT --
And you can only put *one* component into BorderLayout.CENTER per panel. If you put more than one element into the same position of a panel, what gets painted is not well defined, i.e. it may be either of the elements (or both).